# When using read with the -t flag, can I display the time remaining?

Tags: bash, unix

I have an input that times out after a few seconds, but to make it less jarring I would like it to display the time remaining. How can I do this?

Comment: To clarify: You have a large file that you're trying to open with the `read()` function. The function is taking a long time to read the file. So you want to display a counter that shows how long is remaining?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple and good way to do that. Could you instead show a countdown like "Press a key to input, otherwise script will continue in 10..9.."?

Comment: @franklin, no he's using the bash [`read` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with `read -t`, but this script accomplishes a countdown on another line as a background process:

```
#!/bin/bash

function displayCountdown {
  ((remaining=$1))
  while [ $remaining -gt 0 ]
  do
    tput sc # save cursor pos
    tput cuu1 # go up one line
    tput cub 80 # go 80 chars left
    tput el # clear to eol
    ( echo -n "$remaining second(s) remaining" ) >&2
    tput rc # restore saved cursor pos
    ((remaining=remaining-1))
    sleep 1
  done
  echo
}

NUM_SECONDS=5

## the first echo is needed
echo ; displayCountdown $NUM_SECONDS & read -t $NUM_SECONDS ; RC=$? ; kill -9 $! ; wait $! 2>/dev/null

echo "Got ($RC): $REPLY"

exit 0
```

It's not perfect.  For instance, when pressing the delete key, it sometimes produces `^R`'s and messes up the terminal a bit.  But, if you decide to use this, maybe there is some `stty` setting you can use to remedy this.

I tried this on a Mac.  I haven't tried this on Linux.

Comment: The countdown seems to work, but $REPLY is always coming back empty. I tried echo ; displayCountdown $NUM_SECONDS & read -t $NUM_SECONDS REPLY ; RC=$? ; kill -9 $! ; wait $! 2>/dev/null but that didn't seem to do it either. Where should $REPLY get set?

Comment: `read` should set the REPLY variable if no variable name argument is provided.  So, try the read call without the REPLY argument.